# count of entries of XXXX post inquiry date of ABC using group,count and loop in R

Tags: r

I am intended to list-out count of all ID's who have inquired post inquiring ABC(where XXXX means other companies).
Sample table is given below:

```
     ID            Company  INQUIRY-DATE
    A15217177635833 XXXX    25-08-2018
    A15217177635833 ABC     28-06-2018
    A15217177635833 XXXX    05-05-2018
    A15217177635833 XXXX    28-05-2019
    F15039820795577 ABC     22-08-2017
    F15039820795577 XXXX    15-06-2017
    F15039820795577 XXXX    15-08-2018
    F15039820795577 XXXX    25-08-2018
    F15039820795577 XXXX    15-08-2018
```

Expected Output:

```
     ID             Count 
    A15217177635833 2
    F15039820795577 3
```

That means all entries of XXXX post inquiry date of ABC.
I am trying to group, arrange and count the rows but not exactly able to make logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert `INQUIRY-DATE` to date class, `group_by` `ID` and count number of entries which are not `"ABC"` and are greater than `INQUIRY-DATE` at first match of `Company == "ABC"`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(`INQUIRY-DATE` = as.Date(`INQUIRY-DATE`, "%d-%m-%Y")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(`INQUIRY-DATE`[Company != "ABC"] > 
                        `INQUIRY-DATE`[match("ABC", Company)]))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  ID              Count
#  <fct>           <int>
#1 A15217177635833     2
#2 F15039820795577     3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("A15217177635833", "F15039820795577"), class = "factor"), 
Company = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ABC", 
"XXXX"), class = "factor"), `INQUIRY-DATE` = structure(c(5L, 
7L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("05-05-2018", 
"15-06-2017", "15-08-2018", "22-08-2017", "25-08-2018", "28-05-2019", 
"28-06-2018"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, its not working for the combinations where we have 'ABC', 'XXXX' and then again 'ABC'. it is counting 2nd 'ABC' and 'XXXX'. (Apologies i missed to mention this possible combination).

Comment: @Saurabh `match` will return the index of first match. If there are multiple `'ABC'` in your data for each `ID` the current code gets `INQUIRY-DATE` for first '`ABC`' in each group. What would you like to do instead?

Comment: So the idea is to get the details of all occurrences of 'ID's apart from 'ABC' after its first occurrence by date.

Comment: @Saurabh okay..Updated the answer. Can you check the answer now?

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, its working fine now. Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: Hi @Ronak, extension to this question. I have tried it with groupby and mutate but no luck. All the other conditions remain same just i want to divide this count by different purpose. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59542420/12442975