# Count all entries of XXXX post inquiry date of ABC must be divided by their purpose, groupby() with detailing of data

Tags: r

I am intended to list-out count of all purposes per ID who have inquired post inquiring ABC(where XXXX means other companies).
Sample table is given below:

```
     ID            Company  INQUIRY-DATE Purpose
    A15217177635833 XXXX    25-08-2018   X
    A15217177635833 ABC     28-06-2018   Y
    A15217177635833 XXXX    05-05-2018   Z
    A15217177635833 XXXX    28-05-2019   A
    F15039820795577 ABC     22-08-2017   X
    F15039820795577 XXXX    15-06-2017   Y
    F15039820795577 XXXX    15-08-2018   Z
    F15039820795577 XXXX    25-08-2018   Z
    F15039820795577 XXXX    15-08-2018   A
```

Expected Output:

```
     ID             Count_Z  Count_A
    A15217177635833 1         1
    F15039820795577 2         1
```

That means count all entries of XXXX post inquiry date of ABC must be divided by their purpose .
I tried this using group by and mutate(count_z) but no luck.

I am not sure how to get detailed data after group by, because to my knowledge group by is used with summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first convert `INQUIRY-DATE` to date-object, `arrange` data by `ID` and `INQUIRY-DATE` for each group select only those rows which is after first occurrence of `"ABC"`, count each `Purpose` and then spread the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   mutate(`INQUIRY-DATE` = as.Date(`INQUIRY-DATE`, "%d-%m-%Y")) %>%
   arrange(ID, `INQUIRY-DATE`) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(Company != "ABC" & row_number() > match("ABC", Company)) %>%
   count(ID, Purpose) %>%
   tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Purpose, values_from = n, 
                      values_fill = list(n = 0))

#  ID                  A     X     Z
#  <fct>           <int> <int> <int>
#1 A15217177635833     1     1     0
#2 F15039820795577     1     0     2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("A15217177635833", "F15039820795577"), class = "factor"), 
Company = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ABC", 
"XXXX"), class = "factor"), `INQUIRY-DATE` = structure(c(5L, 
7L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("05-05-2018", 
"15-06-2017", "15-08-2018", "22-08-2017", "25-08-2018", "28-05-2019", 
"28-06-2018"), class = "factor"), Purpose = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "X", "Y", 
"Z"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing this. It assumes rows are time-ordered.

```
library(tidyr)

xy <- read.table(text = "     ID            Company  INQUIRY-DATE Purpose
    A15217177635833 XXXX    25-08-2018   X
    A15217177635833 ABC     28-06-2018   Y
    A15217177635833 XXXX    05-05-2018   Z
    A15217177635833 XXXX    28-05-2019   A
    F15039820795577 ABC     22-08-2017   X
    F15039820795577 XXXX    15-06-2017   Y
    F15039820795577 XXXX    15-08-2018   Z
    F15039820795577 XXXX    25-08-2018   Z
    F15039820795577 XXXX    15-08-2018   A", header = TRUE)

xys <- split(xy, f = xy$ID)
xya <- sapply(xys, FUN = function(x) {
  # This assumes there can be more than one ABC, so start from the first one.
  start <- min(which(x$Company == "ABC"))
  post.abc <- x[(start + 1):nrow(x), ]
  data.frame(ID = unique(x$ID), counts = table(post.abc$Purpose))

}, simplify = FALSE)

out <- do.call(rbind, xya)
rownames(out) <- NULL

spread(out, key = counts.Var1, value = counts.Freq)

               ID A X Y Z
1 A15217177635833 1 0 0 1
2 F15039820795577 1 0 1 2
```